# Unable to capture network traffic in Selenium Remote Control for latest Selenium Servers

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

Unable to capture network traffic in Selenium Remote Control for latest Selenium Servers, I am able get up to 2.37 selenium server, as I upgraded FF to 27, i have to upgrade the selenium server to 2.39, but with 2.39 i am unable to capture the network traffic

Comment: If you're only using `selernium-rc`, then you should remove all the other tags. If you're using `selenium-webdriver` with Java, then please provide the relevant piece of code that you have written.